# Flutter breaking arabic words

Tags: android, flutter, arabic

Flutter is breaking the Arabic font in my android app. How can I fix this issue

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] add a [mcve] with question .

Comment: How is it "breaking the font"? Please be more specific. What is your expected output?

Comment: what font are you  using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is. I was using letter spacing in the text widget and also I have to add the style property of the Text widget in order to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The font  you are using is not supporting well Arabic, you need to choose an Arabic font.